# Flash movie with Flash 10.0.2 Apple: only one style embedded

Tags: flash

I tried to embedd four styles of a font in a flash movie (regular, italic, bold and bold italic). The flash movie is exported correctly. The generated size report shows all styles. But flash player displays only the style of the first letter. What is wrong?

Comment: Could you post the code?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot: it is a flash movie for sifr. I used the "as" of sifr3-r436. Here is my size report. A friend had no problems to export all styles with Windows CS4.

### sifr.swf Filmbericht

Bild #    Bild Byte    Gesamt Byte    Szene
------    ---------    -----------    ----------------
      1          61107          61107    Scene 1 (AS 2.0-Klassen Exportbild)

Szene                        Form Byte    Text Byte    ActionScript Byte
-------------------------    ---------    ---------    -----------------
Scene 1                                0             0                   179

Symbol                       Form Byte    Text Byte    ActionScript Byte
-------------------------    ---------    ---------    -----------------
holder                                 0           185                     0

Schriftart                 Byte        Zeichen
-----------------------    --------    -----------
FrutigerNextLT-BoldIt         11723     !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ÀÜÀú‚Äì‚Äî‚Äò‚Äô‚Äö‚Äú‚Äù‚Äû‚Ä†‚Ä°‚Ä¢‚Ä¶‚Ä∞‚Äπ‚Ä∫‚Ç¨‚Ñ¢
FrutigerNextLT-Regular        11438     !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ÀÜÀú‚Äì‚Äî‚Äò‚Äô‚Äö‚Äú‚Äù‚Äû‚Ä†‚Ä°‚Ä¢‚Ä¶‚Ä∞‚Äπ‚Ä∫‚Ç¨‚Ñ¢
FrutigerNextLT-It             11876     !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ÀÜÀú‚Äì‚Äî‚Äò‚Äô‚Äö‚Äú‚Äù‚Äû‚Ä†‚Ä°‚Ä¢‚Ä¶‚Ä∞‚Äπ‚Ä∫‚Ç¨‚Ñ¢
FrutigerNextLT-Bold           11357     !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ÀÜÀú‚Äì‚Äî‚Äò‚Äô‚Äö‚Äú‚Äù‚Äû‚Ä†‚Ä°‚Ä¢‚Ä¶‚Ä∞‚Äπ‚Ä∫‚Ç¨‚Ñ¢

ActionScript Byte    Position
-----------------    --------
               179    Scene 1:code:1
             14245    ActionScript 2.0-Klassen